# when "full back up" screen appears i cannot pick the "back up my data" option

Tags: samsung, windows, droid-explorer

i can't touch and confirm the back up my data option. i am able to pick the "do not back up" option whenever. ive tried adding a password but does not let me back up. im not sure all is update and installed. im running kk 4.4.4 on verizon s5. i downgraded from lollipop if that may be the issue? I dont see how if im already on the full back up prompt.

Comment: In Lollipop and I faced the same problem. I couldn't select the option and it was greyed out. So I dont think you are unable to select the option because you downgraded from Android L to Kitkat.

Comment: i actually got it to work. i had bluelight filter on which decreases the opacity of screen. Anyhow i turned it off and the back up worked. i wasnt able to download apks so this helped. if u have any apps that run ontop of most apps or something like that as it was explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EOBoy77YoQ   i would disable them and then do what you gotta do and redownload. idk why this is happening now because it didnt before but it helped me. hope it helps you!

Comment: But I wasn't using any screen filter apps. The screen was stuck on the Full backup screen with the buttons unselectable and nothing was happening for over half hour. If it worked for you please post it as an answer which will be useful for the future readers. ;)

Comment: so you werent even able to cancel it?

Comment: @user117301 Could you add your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @user117301 there was no cancel button or nothing was happening acutually. Pressing home button got me to the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

I actually got it to work by disabling the screen filtering app. I had applied bluelight filter which decreases the opacity of screen. Anyhow I turned it off and the backup worked. I wasn't able to download apk's so this helped. If u have any apps that run on top of most apps or something like that as it was explained in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EOBoy77YoQ), I would disable them and then do what I want to do and redownload. I don't know why this is happening now because it didn't before but it helped me. Hope it helps you.